# FlutterSession delete values

Tags: flutter, session

Is there a way to remove all session values that are stored in flutter_session ?
I have added values to session like following :

```
        await FlutterSession().set('login_data', jsonEncode(response.body));
        await FlutterSession().set('company_code', jsonEncode(companycode));
```

I need to remove them after logout.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could always set them to empty strings or nulls after you logout.

**Update**
I copied it from other topic

> You don't need to actively delete objects in Dart.
>
> Dart is a garbage-collected language, so any object that you don't
> hold any references to will eventually be garbage collected and freed
> by the runtime system.
>
> So all you have to do is to clear any variables you have that
> reference the object.
>
> Garbage collection is really implicit in the language specification.
> The specification doesn't say so that garbage collection exists (it
> doesn't even mention the concept), but the language and libraries are
> designed in such a way that garbage collection is possible: Objects
> that the program cannot find a reference to anywhere also can't affect
> the program's behavior any more, so it is undetectable that they are
> being collected and deleted by the garbage collector.

so answer would be `x = null`

Comment: no way to destroy session ?

Comment: I updated my answer. @JuniorJ in docs of FlutterSession I didnt find any destroy function.

Comment: ok. thank you for the reply. in the case of shared_preferences, we can clear data using clear(). thought there should be something like this in flutter_session also.

Comment: yeah. there is no such thing here https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_session/latest/flutter_session/FlutterSession-class.html . Maybe try ask it on discord of flutter. You could `var session = FlutterSession()` and then just `session = null`... but im not sure but according to what I have read that would be the answer